# I have group Id of the M365 Group from SharePoint Site, how do I retrieve the m365 group name, looks like it may be deleted

Tags: sharepoint, office365

We have a team site and looks like a user deleted the m365 group attached to it. I have the group ID however unable to restore the m365 email id, is there any way to get to it?

I tried making the new m365 group , making it as default group but nothing is working out.

Comment: Where do you see the group ID, can you add a screenshot where you can see the group ID?